# Cannot access localhost:1234

Tags: php, localhost

I created a server (localhost:1234) by typing in the terminal

```
parcel index.php
```

First thing - it didn't create any files for me. Second- - when trying to access the server in the browser I get `HTTP ERROR 404`

Do u know what may be happening?

Comment: No idea. What is `parcel`? Think you may need to alter your tags `php` doesn't seem like its relevant yet